# When should I use a Front End Module (FEM) for a Wi-Fi chip?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, wireless, wifi, siliconlabs

The [WF200](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/wi-fi/wf200-series-2-transceiver-ics#) from Silicon Labs has the ability to connect a Front End Module (FEM).

I have some questions:

1. Why should I use a FEM?
2. If I need a FEM, then which one fits with the WF200? Can I take an arbitary FEM or should it be a specific one?

[image]

Comment: the first question asks for an opinion

Comment: Have you read AN1226? The first paragraph tells all.

Comment: @Kartman Yes. But I don't understand which IC chip I should use.